# TypeError: list.push is not a function

Tags: reactjs

I was trying ReactJS and got an error. I am trying to push a string into an array of list and when the user clicks the button the following error comes up:

> TypeError: list.push is not a function

I also used the `concat` function but this error comes up there as well.

Here's the function this occurs inside of:

```js
adddata(todovalue){
  if(todovalue !== ""){
    const newitem = {
      id : Date.now(),
      value: todovalue,
      isDone: false
    };
    const list = {...this.state.list};
    list.push(newitem); //This is where the error occurs
    this.setState({
      list,
      newitem : ""
    });
  }
}
```

For context, here's my entire app:

```js
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.png';
import './App.css';

class App extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      newitem : "",
      list : [] 
    };
  }
  adddata(todovalue){
    if(todovalue !== ""){
      const newitem = {
        id : Date.now(),
        value: todovalue,
        isDone: false
      };
      const list = {...this.state.list};
      list.push(newitem);
      this.setState({
        list,
        newitem : ""
      });
    }
  } 
  deleteitem(id){
    const list = [...this.state.list];
    const udate = list.filter(item => item.id !== id);
    this.setState({
      list : udate
    });
  }
  update(input){
    this.setState({
      newitem:input
    });
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <img src={logo} width="100px " className="logo"/>
        <div className="add">
          <p>Enter your name</p><br></br>
          <input type="text" className="input" value={this.state.newitem} onChange={e => this.update(e.target.value)}/>
          <button className="btn" onClick={() => this.adddata(this.state.newitem)}>Add</button>
        </div>
        <div className="list">
          <ul>
            {this.state.list.map(item => {
              return(
                <li key={item.id}>
                    {item.value}
                </li>
              );
            })}
            <li>PLay Csgo</li><button className="del">Delete</button>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Sometimes, it's easy for the question in the title to get lost when reading the question, so I've edited your question to reiterate the error message inline. In addition, I've corrected a formatting issue with the code, as the first line was orphaned from the rest of your code.

Comment: In addition to the above edits, I've also pulled out the function where this error is occurring and left a comment highlighting the specific line that it's occurring on, in order to help focus the community's attention. While I was at it, I also updated the formatting of your main code block so that the indentation is consistent, an added syntax highlighting hints so it's easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to apply spread on a object, spread the array instead and then apply the push operation on the array

Try this instead

```
adddata(todovalue) {
    if (todovalue !== "") {
      const newitem = {
        id: Date.now(),
        value: todovalue,
        isDone: false
      };
      const list = [...this.state.list];
      list.push(newitem);
      this.setState({
        list,
        newitem: ""
      });
    }
  }
```